# VBA Copy/Paste from ranges failing

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range of cells and paste them into a new position of the worksheet I am working on. This is the code I have

```
Dim TemplateArea As Range
Dim TemplateOpening As Range
Dim TemplatePopulate As Range

Dim TemplateWS As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set TemplateWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

    Set TemplateArea = TemplateWS.Range("B6:Q8")
    Set TemplateOpening = TemplateWS.Range("R2:V4")
    Set TemplatePopulate = TemplateWS.Range("B10")

    copyRange TemplateArea, TemplatePopulate
End Sub

Private Sub btn_AddOpening_Click()
    TemplateWS.Range("10:12").Delete

    copyRange TemplateArea, TemplatePopulate
End Sub

Function copyRange(fromRange, toRange As Range)
    fromRange.Copy _
        Destination:=toRange
    ' ^ This is the line it fails at with error code 1004
End Function
```

The error code it gives me on the listed line is Run-time error '1004', "Copy method of Range class failed".

That line of code comes from the Microsoft documentation, and was working earlier during testing. I have tried every other way of copy/pasting, nothing is working.

EDIT:
It seems the error is in the fact that I am deleting the range it will be copying to prior to the copy. I need to clear the range before copying to it, since there will be bad data through out the entire set of rows, so it must all be removed.

Comment: You are trying to copy B6:Q8, 2 cells each Row from B to Q, that's a lot of cells. And you are trying to paste all of this on 2 Cells in one Row, B10:B10. You can only copy a range and paste it on a same sized range.

Comment: My bad, the B10:B10 is an artifact from testing. It should only read B10. It worked perfectly fine as it was like that earlier, so it's not an issue to do with range sizes (I am almost certain of it)

Comment: Code works for me when it is in a module. Do you have a specific reason for the userform?

Comment: This is part of a larger function that will be populating data and so on, so a user interface is mandatory. I just tried putting the function into a module and unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Try it in a "clean" environment. This works for me so if it doesn't work for you the problem is probably with the range itself?https://drive.google.com/file/d/199ZX9O10NgbAqSXmcuU-2PipaYoKRtaK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's bizarre. I've shifted my code around slightly to post here, and it seems that by putting the function into a separate function seems to break it, I will edit my code to show you what I mean

Comment: Seems that the actual issue is the fact that I am deleting all of the rows prior to copying, though I need to clear the entire area prior to copying to ensure that it is all clear of any old data

Comment: You could just use Range.clear instead of delete so you won't have to reset the range.

Comment: I was under the impression that clear only removed the values, when I also needed to remove formatting. This works well, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub btn_AddOpening_Click()
    TemplateWS.Range("10:12").Delete

    Set TemplatePopulate = TemplateWS.Range("B10")
    ' Needed to reset range

    copyRange TemplateArea, TemplatePopulate
End Sub
```

Since the range was deleted, it needed to be reset prior to the copy